# Sharepoint: Establish related records when new item being added to list

Tags: list, sharepoint, relationship

What is the best way to implement a parent-child hierachy between items in a list? The requirement is as follows

```
-> there is a list item with a particular ID
-> that particular ID could have related records.
-> all those related records should show up when viewing the list item
```

When the user adds a new item to list using a form, they should have the option to choose whether the new item being added has another related item or not.

The primary question here is what would be the best way to establish this hierarchy in the list? Also, all the items would be in the same list so how
would we link the list to itself? Or, what would be the best way to implement this? I can figure out several approaches to handle this within the confines of the 
sharepoint server object model; however, this needs to be done primarily within the UI of Sharepoint itself (webparts, features, etc. may be used). However,
I am not sure how to IMPLEMENT THIS WITHIN THE SHAREPOINT CONTAINER ITSELF.

Any ideas/insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a look up column in list with a parent list as itself and allow multiple selections. That way you will be able to check multiple parent IDs for a specific list item.

To show related list items, you can customize details view page of the list in sharepoint designer and add list view web part or dataview with appropriate filters based on the current item.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me go over your answer and get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think I should create different content types and a parent list and a child list?

Comment: Creating content type makes sense if you want to re-use the structure at lots of places. It will be easy to manage using content type. Parent-child lists should be only created when your information is totally different from each other. For example, if you are creating hierarchy of categories, single list is enough and you can maintain category tree structure using it. So, it depends on your case.